# DataTables sort by number by default

Tags: javascript, sorting, datatables

I am pulling some data from my back end, and showing them in a DataTables table. The problem is that it doesn't sort its rows based on the appending number at the end, which is what I'm trying to do. I am pasting a screenshot of the problem. Any help appreciated.

[image]

EDIT: This way I am providing the JSON to DataTables

```
$finalTableSQL = "select * from players_data where store = $store";
$finalTableResult = $mysqli->query($finalTableSQL);
$rows = array();
while ($row = $finalTableResult->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

$returnToCashier = [];
$returnToCashier["data"] = [];
foreach ($rows as $finalTableRows) {
    $playerID = (int) $finalTableRows["user_id"];
    $playerEmail = $userRow["email"];
    $lastintype = (int) $finalTableRows["last_in_type"];
    $lastIN = (float) $finalTableRows["last_in"] / 100;

    if ($lastintype == 0) {
        $intype = "Cash";
    } else if ($lastintype == 1) {
        $intype = "Privilege";
    } else {
        $intype = "Bonus";
    }

    $canCashOut = (int) $finalTableRows["can_cash_out"];

    if ($canCashOut == 0) {
        $credits = "<font style='color: red;'>" . ((float) $finalTableRows["credits"] / 100) . " €</font>";
    } else {
        $credits = ((float) $finalTableRows["credits"] / 100) . " €";
    }

    $playeruserSQL = "select * from directus_users where id = $playerID";
    $playeruserResult = $mysqli->query($playeruserSQL);
    $playeruserRow = $playeruserResult->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    array_push($returnToCashier["data"], [
        "username" => str_replace("@mail.com", "", $playeruserRow["email"]),
        "credits" => $credits,
        "lastintype" => $lastIN . " € " . $intype,
        "lastplayed" => $finalTableRows["last_played"],
        "playerid" => $playerID,
    ]);
}

echo json_encode($returnToCashier);
```

And this way I'm showing the JSON to the front end:

```
var table = $('#playerstable').DataTable({
    "fnDrawCallback": function(data) {
        $(".paginate_button > a").on("focus", function() {
            $(this).blur();
        });
    },
    "ajax": "/frontend/cashierusers.php?token=" + sessionStorage.getItem('JWT'),
    "columns": [{
            "data": "username"
        },
        {
            "data": "credits"
        },
        {
            "data": "lastintype"
        },
        {
            "data": "lastplayed"
        },
        {
            "data": "playerid"
        },
    ],
    "autoWidth": false,
    rowReorder: false,
    responsive: true,
    language: {
        search: "_INPUT_",
        searchPlaceholder: "Search..."
    }
});
```

Comment: Please include some code.

Comment: @NullDev just did, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the following techniques:

1 - Create a hidden column containing only the numeric portion of each value.

2 - Use the [`orderData`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderData) option to allow your visible column to be sorted by the data in the hidden column.

In my test case, I am loading my data from a JavaScript variable, not from an ajax URL - but otherwise the approach would work the same way for you:

My test table:

```
<table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>hidden column</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

The DataTable:

```js
  var dataSet = [
    {"playerid": "rodplayer25"},
    {"playerid": "rodplayer10"},
    {"playerid": "rodplayer2"},
    {"playerid": "rodplayer1"}
  ];

  $(document).ready(function() {

    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
      "data": dataSet,
      "columnDefs": [
        {
          "targets": [ 0 ],
          // use the data in the 2nd (hidden) column for ordering this column:
          "orderData": [ 1 ],
          "data": "playerid"
        },
        {
          "targets": [ 1 ],
          "visible": false,
          "data": function ( row, type, val, meta ) {
            // populate this column with only the trailing number:
            return parseInt(row.playerid.split(/([0-9]+)/)[1]);
          }
        }
      ]
    } );

  } );
```

This will display your original "rodplayer" data values. But when you sort on that column, it will use the numeric data extracted from the end of each string.

The regular expression I use (`/([0-9]+)/`) assumes the numeric data always occurs at the end of each value. So, as long as your data never deviates from this format, the regex will work as expected.

[image]